# Redirect Commons logging without editing the jar or SLF4J, via external properties file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I have a .jar file (foo.jar, for instance) that we can't alter that contains a commons-logging.properties file (that redirects to JDK14Logging) and relies on an external commons-logging.jar file for it's logging. This, I believe is set to simply output to stdout which isn't very helpful.

We have a different logging system (log4J if it matters) that we are using, and would prefer to use. Is it possible to have an external properties file (sitting local to the foo.jar) that 'overrides' the one *inside* foo.jar?

I'm aware that SLF4J *should* work, as should editing the .jar in 7zip and 'recompiling' so to speak, but I feel that the first creates an extra dependency on a Jar (as requires bringing one into the environment) and the latter creates a dependency on someone to make the same edits we made to foo.jar to foo2.jar when/if we are provided with that when/if I have left the project.

Is this possible **without editing the jar or SLF4J?**? Or do I need to bite one of the aforementioned bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix (assuming the default classloaders are being used) would be to create your own `commons-logging.properties` file, contained in a directory that is on the classpath before the jar containing the unwanted `commons-logging.properties` file.  Your `commons-logging.properties` file should be configured to use Log4J and in particular your `log4j.properties` file.

However I'd really recommend switching to SLF4J and using the SLF4J [bridge implementation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) of commons-logging, which will make the commons-logging API being used by the libraries on which you depend irrelevant and allow you to control the log configuration from your project (via a single logback.xml file assuming you're using Logback).

Comment: This isn't that relevant. I'm not asking about how to use SLF4J - I know how that works. And it's not clear either whether you're saying this is the *only* option. As it stands it reads as though you're giving me an opinion, not an answer.

Comment: I'd understood from your original question that you were using SLF4J, however, given this isn't the case I'll update my answer

Comment: That's a fantastic answer now. Cheers.